# How can I add a subquery to a query in Laravel app?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have users and customers tables.

Each of my users have a predefined set of queries. For examples `basic` user and only see customers with type `new` and `potential`.

How can I write a query where user selects to see only `potential` clients, or only clients with certain names?

The way I do it now is simply

```
$defaultQuery = [['type', 'new'],['type', 'potential']];
$customQuery = ['type', 'new']; // I would pass this, can be null

$customers = Customer::where($defaultQuery[0][0], $defaultQuery[0][1])->orWhere($defaultQuery[1][0], $defaultQuery[1][1])->get();

$customersToReturn = [];

if ($customQuery) {
    foreach($customers as $customer) {
        if ($customer[$customQuery[0]] == $customQuery[1]) {
            $customerToReturn[] = $customer;
        }
    }
} else {
    $customersToReturn = $customers;
}
return $customersToReturn;
```

I know there's a filter() function but I want to make one query with the subquery. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you need to combine 2 `where` clauses into one, and then conditonally apply `orWhere`? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#or-where-clauses

Comment: @OstapBrehin my custom query has to a refined result of the main query. It will not be orWhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the responsibilities of these queries on the models and relations themselves

```
//User.php

public function potentialCustomer(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Customer::class)->where('type', '=', 'potential');
}

public function newCustomer(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Customer::class)->where('type', '=', 'new');
}
```

With this you control only the call in the controller.Something like this:

```
//controller
$customers = $user->isBasic() ? $user->newCustomer : $user->potentialCustomer;
```